# About the proof in Topology Willard S. theorem 31.2

Tags: general-topology

I have trouble to understand a few things in the proof:

1) Why is C connected?  I understand that every $C_n$ is connected, and $C_{n+1}$ $\subseteq$ $C_n$. So if the intersection (that defines C) was finite, it is clear that C is connected. But how can I prove that C is connected when the intersection is infinite?

2) Why are A,B open? I see that $A_n$, $B_n$ are open, but C is closed. So how can I prove that the intersection is open?

3) Why do I need to regard the diameter of the sets? and why there is necessarily V of diameter<1/2?

I couldn't find the page of the proof in google, so here it is.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the compactness and normality of $C_1$.

   They are open in $C$, nobody says it's open in $X$.

   You need that the thickness of the chains goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity. How would you know that $A ∪ B = C \setminus \{x\}$?

Comment: thanks, I can see now 1,2. But I still don't understand why there is V of diameter<1/2

Comment: @alexkur Well, you don't need specifically $1/2$, you just want $diam(U_{ni_n}) \to 0$ as $n \to ∞$.

Comment: That I understand. I see why I should demand such V, what I don't understand is why there exist such V

Comment: The space is locally connected so for any $x ∈ U$, where $U$ is open, there exist arbitrary small $V$s which are open, connected, and $x ∈ V ⊆ U$. We just take such $V$ with $diam < 1/2$.